# Terraform - For expression Understanding

Tags: terraform

I am trying to understand the "for" expressions in TF when they use the pair of temporary symbols like k,v. My goal here is to understand the construct so that I can put this knowledge into a PowerPoint file and explain it to others. I'll do my best to explain what I think is happening in plain English, but would like your input to see if my understanding is correct or not. I'm learning TF, so please bear with me here.

Below is the code - inherited from someone else.

**Variable Declaration**

```
variable "private_dns_zones" {
  type = map(object({
    dns_zone_name       = string
    resource_group_name = string
    tags                = map(string)
    vnet_links = list(object({
      zone_to_vnet_link_name    = string
      vnet_name                 = string
      networking_resource_group = string
      zone_to_vnet_link_exists  = bool
      vnet_link_rg_name         = string
    }))
    zone_exists          = bool
    registration_enabled = bool
  }))
  description = "Map containing Private DNS Zone Objects"
  default     = {}
}
```

**MAIN - Cut off to limit the scope of this**

```
locals {
  rgs_map = {
    for i, n in var.private_dns_zones : "${i}" => {
      name = n.resource_group_name
    }
  }
  private_dns_zones = {
    for dz_k, dz_v in var.private_dns_zones :
    dz_k => dz_v if(coalesce(dz_v.zone_exists, false) == false && dz_v.dns_zone_name != null)
  }

  zone_to_vnet_links_distinct = distinct(flatten([
    for dz_k, dz_v in var.private_dns_zones : [
      for vnet in coalesce(dz_v.vnet_links, []) : {
        dns_zone_key              = dz_k #This would be 'zone1'?
        dns_zone_name             = dz_v.dns_zone_name
        zone_to_vnet_link_name    = vnet.zone_to_vnet_link_name
        vnet_name                 = vnet.vnet_name
        networking_resource_group = vnet.networking_resource_group
        vnet_link_rg_name         = vnet.vnet_link_rg_name
        registration_enabled      = dz_v.registration_enabled
      } if(coalesce(vnet.zone_to_vnet_link_exists, false) == false && vnet.vnet_name != null)
    ] if(dz_v.zone_exists == false && dz_v.dns_zone_name != null)
  ]))

  zone_to_vnet_links = {
    for vnet_link in local.zone_to_vnet_links_distinct :
    "${vnet_link.dns_zone_key}_${vnet_link.zone_to_vnet_link_name}" => vnet_link
  }
}
```

**TFVARS**

```
private_dns_zones = {
  zone1 = {
    dns_zone_name       = "privatelink.vaultcore.azure.net"
    resource_group_name = "Terraform1"
    tags = {
      iac    = "Terraform"
      syntax = "zone1"
    }
    zone_exists = false
    vnet_links = [
      {
        zone_to_vnet_link_name    = "vaultcore-vnet-eastus2-01"
        vnet_name                 = "vnet-eastus2-01"
        networking_resource_group = "Terraform1"
        zone_to_vnet_link_exists  = false
        vnet_link_rg_name         = "Terraform1"
      }
    ]
    registration_enabled = false
  }
}
```

"a 'for' expression can optionally declare a pair of temporary symbols in order to use the key or index of each item too"

So, for the locals rgs_map seen above:
`for i, n in var.private_dns_zones : "${i} => {name = n.resource_group_name}`

My interpretation:
i refers to the key or attribute name. So, this means "zone1" as seen in the tfvars file?

for zone1, loop through the object and create a new object (as depicted by the {} brackets) that uses 'zone1' as its index, and create one argument per index that has 'name' with the value set to the value of the resource_group_name in the tfvars file? **Is this explanation correct?**

Representation of this:
**IS THIS ACCURATE??**

```
rgs_map = {
   zone1 = {
      name = value of resource_group_name in tfvars file
   }
}
```

**Next One**
locals private_dns_zones
for dz_k, dz_v :
**dz_k refers to 'zone1' again?**

Interpretation:
zone1 => dz_v (does dz_v refer to the whole object? Not clear on this.)
create a new local object if zone_exists is false and the dns_zone_name is not null??

Representation of this:
**IS THIS ACCURATE??**

```
private_dns_zones = {
     zone1 = {
       name = dns_zone_name
       resource_group_name = resource_group_name
       etc.
}
}
```

Thanks. Just want some confirmation that my understanding of these is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first:

`TFVARS` or `.tfvars` files are optional. The reason why we have them is to store the input. If we remove them, Terraform will ask us for the input when you do the `plan`.

`variables` are data structures which accept and store input provided by us using `.tfvar` files or typing the input in from the console. In your case the structure of `private_dns_zones` from the `TFVARS` files provides input to the `variable "private_dns_zones"`.

`for` expressions:

They behave differently based on what they iterate on. For example:
Having on variable as the iterator while iterating through a list:

```
[for item in ["abc", "bcd", "cde"] : upper(s)]
```

The value of `item` in this case will be `"abc"`, `"bcd"` and "cde"`.

Having and index and an iterator while iterating through a list:

```
[for index, item in ["abc", "bcd", "cde"] : upper(s)]
```

The value of `item` will be `"abc"`, `"bcd"` and "cde", meanwhile the value of `index` will be `0`, `1` and `2`.

Iterating through a `map`:

```
{ for key, value in var.private_dns_zones : "${key}" => {name = n.resource_group_name} }
```

In case of `map` and `objects` we don't have indexes. We have keys and values. The value `key` will be `zone1` and the value of `value` will be the whole object of:

```
{
    dns_zone_name       = "privatelink.vaultcore.azure.net"
    resource_group_name = "Terraform1"
    tags = {
      iac    = "Terraform"
      syntax = "zone1"
    }
    zone_exists = false
    vnet_links = [
      {
        zone_to_vnet_link_name    = "vaultcore-vnet-eastus2-01"
        vnet_name                 = "vnet-eastus2-01"
        networking_resource_group = "Terraform1"
        zone_to_vnet_link_exists  = false
        vnet_link_rg_name         = "Terraform1"
      }
    ]
    registration_enabled = false
}
```

> for zone1, loop through the object and create a new object (as depicted by the {} brackets) that uses 'zone1' as its index, and create one argument per index that has 'name' with the value set to the value of the resource_group_name in the tfvars file? Is this explanation correct?

No, not entirely. The `for` expression will result in an object, but objects don't have indexes, they have keys and values. More correctly would be, this for expression creates an object of which keys are they keys from the `var.private_dns_zones` and the values are the `resource_group_names` to which each key (`zone1`) maps to.

So:

```
rgs_map = {
  for i, n in var.private_dns_zones : "${i}" => {
    name = n.resource_group_name
  }
}
```

Evaluates to:

```
rgs_map = {
  "zone1" = {
    "name" = "Terraform1"
  }
}
```

In case of the second `for` expression, the idea is the same.

```
  private_dns_zones = {
    for dz_k, dz_v in var.private_dns_zones :
    dz_k => dz_v if(coalesce(dz_v.zone_exists, false) == false && dz_v.dns_zone_name != null)
  }
```

This uses the [`coalesce`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/coalesce) function for additional logic on what to include in the object, but other than this is the idea is similar. The output of this is:

```
private_dns_zones = {
  "zone1" = {
    "dns_zone_name" = "privatelink.vaultcore.azure.net"
    "registration_enabled" = false
    "resource_group_name" = "Terraform1"
    "tags" = {
      "iac" = "Terraform"
      "syntax" = "zone1"
    }
    "vnet_links" = [
      {
        "networking_resource_group" = "Terraform1"
        "vnet_link_rg_name" = "Terraform1"
        "vnet_name" = "vnet-eastus2-01"
        "zone_to_vnet_link_exists" = false
        "zone_to_vnet_link_name" = "vaultcore-vnet-eastus2-01"
      },
    ]
    "zone_exists" = false
  }
}
```

> nterpretation: zone1 => dz_v (does dz_v refer to the whole object? Not clear on this.) create a new local object if zone_exists is false and the dns_zone_name is not null??

This is somewhat correct. The object will be created anyway, but it will contains data only about zones for which `zone_exists` is false and `dns_zone_name` is not null. Keep in mind, you could have multiple zones. If no zone has false for `zone_exists` and not null for `dns_zone_name`, than the `private_dns_zones` will be an empty object: `private_dns_zones = {}`.

Some suggestions for debugging Terraform code:

You can use `output` in order to see to what does an expression evaluate to:

```
output "private_dns_zones" {
  value = local.private_dns_zones
}
```

After an `apply` the value of `private_dns_zones` will be displayed in your terminal.

You can use the `terraform console` command to start a new REPL and evaluate terraform commands on the fly.

Comment: Thank you Ervin. That has cleared up so much for me, especially that the maps/objects do not use an Index. This makes more sense now. I am going to add another part of the code to the MAIN section if you can help explain it as well. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

not too sure if this is possible but in the scenario above

```
[for item in ["abc", "bcd", "cde"] : upper(s)]
The value of item in this case will be "abc", "bcd" and "cde".
```

```
Having and index and an iterator while iterating through a list:

[for index, item in ["abc", "bcd", "cde"] : upper(s)]
The value of item will be "abc", "bcd" and "cde", meanwhile the value of index will be 0, 1 and 2.
```

I'm trying to get this to work without having an index number associated to my module